# .htaccess force https but exclude a subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I exclude a subdomain from getting forced to https and redirected to main url? I'm using the below in my .htaccess file but need a little help as my subdomain (stage.mydomain.com) gets redirected / can't access.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried a few options but no luck - Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your first rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^stage\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I gave it a go but it didn't work for some reason. I'm not sure if this matters but I've got mod_spdy on apache. What's weird is that before I installed spdy I had two subdomains set up - and after installing spdy and adding the above (current) htaccess, I was still able to get to those. But if I try and set another one up it get redirected to main url? Any additional thoughts?

Comment: I'm really not sure what changed but all is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.